# Swift enum + associated value + inline case check

Tags: swift, enums, associated-types, quick-nimble

I have the following swift enum for returning an async API-Response:

```
enum Result<U: Equatable> {
  case success(output: U)
  case failure(error: Error)
}
```

For simplifying my Unit test implementation i would like to check if the returned result-enum of one of my methods equals success

I know that i can unwrap the result-enum by using the following statement

```
if case Result.success(let configuration) = result {
    // use unwrapped configuration object
}
```

What i would like to archive is using a single line statement to check if the result is success when checking with `expect`

```
expect(case Result.success(let configuration) = result).to(beTrue()) <-- not compiling
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you goal is to check only success/failure (not the details of success or failure cases) you can extend you enum with read-only variables `isSuccess` and `isFailure`:

```
enum Result<U: Equatable> {

    case success(output: U)
    case failure(error: Error)

    var isSuccess: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .success:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
    var isFailure: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .failure:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

And expect the result to be a success:

```
expect(result.isSuccess)
```